# Tatamibari solver

Tags: code-golf, grid, puzzle-solver

### Background

**[Tatamibari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tatamibari)** is a logic puzzle designed by Nikoli.

A Tatamibari puzzle is played on a rectangular grid with three different kinds of symbols in it: `+`, `-`. and `|`. The solver must partition the grid into rectangular or square regions according to the following rules:

- Every partition must contain exactly one symbol in it.
- A `+` symbol must be contained in a square.
- A `|` symbol must be contained in a rectangle with a greater height than width.
- A `-` symbol must be contained in a rectangle with a greater width than height.
- Four pieces may never share the same corner. (This is how Japanese tatami tiles are usually placed.)

The following is an example puzzle, with a solution:

[image: Example Tatamibari puzzle] [image: Example Tatamibari puzzle solution]

### Task

Solve the given Tatamibari puzzle.

### Input & output

The input is a 2D grid that represents the given Tatamibari puzzle. Each cell contains one of the four characters: `+`, `-`, `|`, and a character of your choice to represent a non-clue cell. In the test cases, an asterisk `*` is used.

You can choose any suitable output format which can unambiguously represent any valid solution to a Tatamibari puzzle. This includes, but is not limited to: (if in doubt, ask in comments.)

- A list of 4-tuples, where each tuple includes the top index, left index, width and height of a rectangle (or any equivalent representation)
- A numeric grid of the same shape as the input, where each number represents a rectangle
- A list of coordinate sets, where each set includes all the coordinates of the cells in a rectangle

If a puzzle has multiple solutions, you can output any number (one or more) of its valid solutions. The input is guaranteed to have at least one solution.

### Test cases

```
Puzzle:
|-*
*+|
*-*
Solution:
122
134
554
=====
Puzzle:
+***
**|*
*+**
***-
Solution:
1122
1122
3322
3344
======
Puzzle:
|*+*+
*****
****-
***+|
+****
Solution:
12233
12233
44444
55667
55667
=======
Puzzle:
****-**
**-**|*
*|*****
****-**
*******
**+*|**
*****+*
One possible solution:
1122222
1133344
1155544
1155544
6667744
6667788
6667788
===========
Puzzle:
*-****|+**
+*-******|
****+*****
*-******||
**++|*****
+****-|***
-****-**+*
********-*
|*+*+|****
*-*--**+*+
Solution:
1111122334
5666622334
7777822994
7777A2299B
CCDEA2299B
CCFFFFGGHH
IIIIJJGGHH
KLLMMNGGOO
KLLMMNGGPP
QQRRSSSTPP
```

### Rules

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. The shortest code in bytes wins.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>417</s> <s>374</s> 366 bytes

Input is list of lines, `~` for non-clue.
Outputs a single solution to stderr in the format `(x_start, width, y_start, height)`.

```python
R=range
k=input()
X,Y=len(k[0]),len(k)
W,H=R(X),R(Y)
Q=[[]]
for q in Q:C=[(x,y)for(a,b,c,d)in q for x in(a,a+b)for y in(c,c+d)];max(map(C.count,C+W))<4>0<all(sum(w>x-s>-1<y-t<h<[c for r in k[t:t+h]for c in r[s:s+w]if'~'>c]==['+|-'[cmp(h,w)]]for(s,w,t,h)in q)==1for x in W for y in H)>exit(q);Q+=[q+[(s,w+1,t,h+1)]for s in W for w in R(X-s)for t in H for h in R(Y-t)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RVDBbuIwEL37KywueGRnRdI9hTgXLr2CVqLI8sEYt44IToiNkkiIX6dxKraSNZp5b96b8bRjsI3Lns8d75T7MujMK9feAgH0wQ68No6cxUoCmzNAe/bOd@QD2I4cAG25EFKiz6bDV1w5vM03XJCBjTBBRLEj0@wEE3HFsWeYeiZU0WPk8RhLzTQ9gVxf1EAuqiWbP7q5ucA2dA9Q/C1Xhapr4m8X0pdD4sskLcYkFLYQevbs4tyzCHmgVkZAR6ATPve0l9Xn8rEsteRcLOk9WQp9aYllPcjYSzzrWWB23hA4T19L4j1@LYjfoTRDFcgV1lvKxZWKKKNpFNIU5pn@V9PHdLpQ4uc/htliZuwPc0gCyOdzQR8LtqD3BUL/bBUNpqvjzrSd8cYFnyP6QPSOUG8rbbFWDh8NblUXqsaZU/QK1kzGdd30lfvCvRpzlGboLUMozTFZMZwyHCOgbKrTV50BevvPxwff) This is too inefficient for the suggested test cases.

---

### Ungolfed

```python
grid = input()
total_width = len(grid[0])
total_height = len(grid)

partitions = [[]]

for partition in partitions:
    # list the corners of all rectangles in the current partition
    corners = [(x, y)
               for (start_x, width, start_y, height) in partition
               for x in (start_x, start_x + width)
               for y in (start_y, start_y + height)]
    # if no corners appears more than three times ...
    if corners != [] and max(map(corners.count, corners)) < 4:
        # .. and all fields are covered by a single rectangle ...
        if all(
                sum(width > x - start_x > -1 < y - start_y < height
                    for (start_x, width, start_y, height) in partition) == 1
                for x in range(total_width)
                for y in range(total_height)):
            # ... and all rectangles contain a single non-~
            # symbol that matches their shape:
            if all(
                [char for row in grid[start_y: start_y + height]
                    for char in row[start_x:start_x + width] if '~' > char]
                == ['+|-'[cmp(height, width)]]
                    for (start_x, width, start_y, height) in partition):
                # output the current partition and stop the program
                exit(partition)

    # append each possible rectangle in the grid to the current partition,
    # and add each new partition to the list of partitions.
    partitions += [partition + [(start_x, width + 1, start_y, height + 1)]
                   for start_x in range(total_width)
                   for width in range(total_width - start_x)
                   for start_y in range(total_height)
                   for height in range(total_height - start_y)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVXbjtowEH33V0zhgVgJaGH7FJX9ir6haGWCIZYSO7JNQ6QVv07HiXMBQlVVRQhie85czvFMytpmSm5ut5MWB9iCkOXZBpRYZVn@WYmDzXA35zJwBru3pDvKuDhldnRGCSmZtsIKJQ3u73ZJQshRaei30fuwMDEB/MwhF8aCzTikSkuuDagjsDwHzVPL5CnnxuEag7PWXNrBR@Ohg2HI4BJBTZvd0cflEBiLoE88b2qKoF3XEbSF0LvcpjxcnMXgxj9A2DqcDFqPIHUfEiE@ZuIZEEeQqq@DlSVn@F8ozbFs5mrXHB9FgVSsVqsGhZgO8A0rT4DJAxTsEhSsDPzJKlVnaaPOkFL4Ad/jPtM5Omtgju2j4PkBg2unwy@u@QH2NTAwwkkwiNEn4JNAbPBYO5hzEbR35wN5W/ZkfcByjTnU/VaNq5aMJx//phyF7RbWBF4JqLEIHoxuN520rR9tfSwa35k7BgcKRxc2VdIydNHzJ5VcXh@wpi72KncSW1TOphkC8ZoLDSZjJb8P9YrqXZox3eSsVeWybvrUcxQ/3bnkJc@NH1e1qjz8Ej9c8sRlsbguUEdn/ewLud8twq/lYpcWZdBG9LrRJPlfEsdPjuagzhYH1/SUaAQyVpXNcanVSbPiyQe/CBsMQYjvTdeNCOcszaBUxoj9XTf4ydRMT6um40edK3dPDt6X5NUoQw9tRiGOv2FItr02GqwhUjzgQpx59@Th1vqJQLdJJ/l39Hcq/117eFAbbAoy9Dv9c8RXTfYK5WuZBA0TBeu83WbhdRbNwq8ZIT8zYdrXGspWam5QG3z3hFcSfhFSZQLFSHHI7nlLs5I4@rysR5XnqsIOhorVMVlvyPuGkHUMwVvkaHa/lGxwve7WG0re@3P3pb8B)

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 193 bytes

Returns all possible solutions as grids with -1, -2 … indicating rooms. There is room for improvements, but the `((((((` started to confuse me. :-)

```
[:(#~0=0(e.,)"2])'*+-|'([:,/(([(<./@,@:<:@[`]`[}{.<@:+"1,/@(#:i.)@{:)"2((((({(0,=/,</,>/)@$)~0({.*(1=#)*0<{.)@-.~,);.0~*[:*/0<1{])"2#]){.([,:-~)"1/>:))[(#~0<:,)~,/@(#:i.)@$)"2)^:(1#.*@,)@,:@i.]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##1ZHLTsMwEEX3/gqrqZQZv9PlNKksIbFixdYKVEKtKBs@wCa/HmynhSIeeyIl9ozPvTMTv8wr0x75QLzlijtO@dWG39zf3c6BoJnc4OBgFK42I7ZC6tRCIGUBAvTGeuWpJx/24z68RdN7kqtOWQ8NnQz6SFkH5Yng1GBVb9XOol/j5CAaAd3QoHB9zKw2k8KtcZMIJKzruzhmcTNiNBAU6QlXnd0RYihd9aRw@iy0zig@EHSNEV6hV@RPZpyRsWMd7vdRcr4TvjHJq2zxb0ZjjB2enl85bLU/Ig9b87jhUO8PWdKCCZmYyCv@BUohMilSwetO6L8FKXOycAud8fzJlWTNfJF@01a@6vRSMl35nNclluVoieW1a@d4NPxHb13gVIaQyz5HbDFYTC/JkpXyXLoe6hIwfW5DfjRS/l6dN10cdD2XDOd3) For the larger test cases I provided `ff` that has a filter `[:(#~1*@#.|@,"2)` for intermediate steps, where empty grids got added because of padding.

#### How it works

- `'*+-|' … i.]` Map `*+-|` to `0 1 2 3`.
- `,/@(#:i.)@$` From all the tiles
- `[(#~0<:,)~` that aren't part of a room,
- `{.([,:-~)"1/>:` starting from the most top-left tile, that isn't part of a room yet, try every possible rectangle spanning down-right.
- `…"2#]` For that rectangle to be valid for the next step,
- `[:*/0<1{]` 0.) it must have a positive size in each dimension
- `0({.*(1=#)*0<{.)@-.~,` 1.) no tile must be part of a room, 2.) exactly one symbol must be within the rectangle,
- `(({(0,=/,</,>/)@$)~` 3.) the dimension of the rectangle fulfill the constraint of the symbol.
- `(<./@,@:<:@[`]`[}{.<@:+"1,/@(#:i.)@{:)"2` For every valid rectangle, copy the current grid and place the next room.
- `^:(1#.*@,)@,:` We need to do this `n` times, where `n` is the number of symbols.
- `[:(#~0=0(e.,)"2])` After this there might be grids that have `n` rooms, but still empty tiles; those must be filtered out.